# How to set height and width of video element in percent

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am trying give a video `width:100%; height:90%;`. I have something like this:

```
<video id='video' >
         <source src='test..mp4' type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

CSS

```
#video{
   display: block;
   width:100%;
   max-height:90%;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: black;
}
```

I can't seem to set 90% for my height unless I use 1200px or 1000px.

I want my video to cover 90% of the height of my screen. How do I do this?

Comment: it seems you've set `max-height` and it might not be applying, have you tried `height: 90%`?

Comment: Have you remembered to set `height:100%` on `html` and `body` (and explicit height on all parent elements)?

Comment: max-height is a limit, it's not a "make it 90%", it just says to not allow this element to go past 90% of the height of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set every parent element to 100% height;

Answer (score 0):

just change the max-height for height only

```
height:90%;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried not setting a width at all and setting the height to 90%

```
#video{
   display: block;
   max-height:90%;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: black;
}
```